# Plotting curve for $\sin(\pi*\sin(x))$ by general angle formula for sine i.e. (n*pi)+(-1)^(n)theta

Tags: trigonometry

So I am using general angle formula for sine. Here i am proceeding as follows: 
Part 1: Finding all angles for $ \sin (\pi*\sin x) = 1. $ So, $ \sin(\pi*\sin(x)) = \sin(\pi/2)$  or $\pi*\sin(x) = (n*\pi)+(-1)^n*(\pi/2)$. Now, I divided it into two parts namely (a) When 'n' is odd and (b) When 'n' is even. By taking 'n' as odd and cancelling $\pi$ then the formula becomes $\sin(x) = n-(1/2)$. Solving RHS for inequality $-1<(n-(1/2)<1$, I got value for $n$ between $[-1/2,3/2]$. So, I choose $n = 0$ and $1$ (integral value in the interval $[-1/2,3/2]$) and I got $\theta$ as $(-\pi/6)$ and $(\pi/6)$. Hence, it means that if I put both value of $\theta$ 
 thus obtained in the original equation I should get result as 1. But, this is not the case with $(-\pi/6)$. Since $\sin(-\pi/6)$ is $(-1/2)$ and then $\sin(\pi*(-1/2))$ is -1 which is clearly not equal to 1.

Please tell me wher I am doing wrong?
This is the same approach I am following for $\sin(\pi*\sin(x)) = -1$ and $0$

Comment: Your paragraph is dense, hard to read.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience. I know that it is hard to read but I am learning how to write equations on this forum. Eventually I will learn how to write expression more clearly.

Comment: The problem is not with the equations.

Comment: ok. Next time i will try to write my problem in more concise manner.

Comment: No, improve spacing !

Answer (score 1):

You got troubled by all these cases. It is simpler to work out the symmetries first.

The function$$f(x):=\sin(\pi\>\sin x)$$ is $2\pi$-periodic and odd. It follows that we need to study $f$ only on the interval $0\leq x\leq\pi$. Furthermore the symmetry $$\sin\bigl({\pi\over2}+t\bigr)=\sin\bigl({\pi\over2}-t\bigr)$$ allows to constrain to the interval $0\leq x\leq{\pi\over2}$. When we have the graph in this interval the rest can be found by reflections and translations.

While $0\leq x\leq{\pi\over2}$ the inner function $g(x):=\pi \sin x$ increases monotonically from $0$ to $\pi$. It follows that $f(x)=\sin\bigl(g(x)\bigr)$ increases from $0$ to $1$ and then decreases again from $1$ to $0$. Etcetera.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin(\pi \sin x)=1\iff \pi\sin x=\frac\pi2+2k\pi\iff \sin x=\frac12+2k$$ and only $\sin x=\dfrac12$ is possible.

> $$x=\frac\pi6+2m\pi\lor x=\frac{5\pi}6+2m\pi.$$

[image]

Comment: I have got points for $sin(\pi*\sin\theta)=1$. But for $sin(\pi*\sin\theta)=-1$ general value for $\theta$ I am getting is $2n\pi-(\pi/2)$ and $2n\pi+(3*\pi/2)$. Unfortunately after putting value for n both expressions are giving e same vlaue of $\theta$

Comment: @AnuragGupta: is this a problem ?